# cURL POST request issue

Tags: curl, post, get, httprequest, httpresponse

I'm trying to use `google safe browsing API` for checking the categorization of any given URL.

As per google safebrowsing API page (https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/v4/lookup-api) , I'm issuing `cURL` to `POST` a `HTTP` request and check for the website categorization.

In return , I'm not seeing any response for what i have POST'ed.

Response Received:

```
#{}
```

Command Used :

```
#curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '  { "client": { "clientId": "Test", "clientVersion": "1.0.0" }, "threatInfo": { "threatTypes": ["MALWARE", "SOCIAL_ENGINEERING"], "platformTypes": ["WINDOWS"], "threatEntryTypes": ["URL"], "threatEntries": [ {"url": "http://www.facebook.com"} ] } }' https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/threatMatches:find?key=AIzaSyD1IMgjaHEza6e9m_jwtjBgPmJX0IMKKIs HTTP/1.1
```

I have checked the command , But not sure where i'm making mistakes. Any thoughts people ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, probably the URL you tested (**www.facebook.com**) is safe according to Google - because if I issue your command but for **ianfette.org**, I get this response:

```
{
  "matches": [
    {
      "threatType": "MALWARE",
      "platformType": "WINDOWS",
      "threat": {
        "url": "http://ianfette.org"
      },
      "cacheDuration": "300s",
      "threatEntryType": "URL"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: We need to place an valid API key where i have X'ed. Will update with API key anyway.